# Terraform EKS module: refer to resources created by eks_managed_node_groups

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 19.0"
  ...
  #this throws error
  kms_key_users = ["${eks_managed_node_groups.incidents-primary-ng.iam_role_arn}"]
  ...
  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    incidents-primary-ng = {
      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 2
      desired_size = 1
    }
  }

}

#this works
output "ng_iam_role_arn" {
  description = "ng_iam_role_arn"
  value       = try(module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups.incidents-primary-ng.iam_role_arn, null)
}
```

This line `kms_key_users = ["${eks_managed_node_groups.incidents-primary-ng.iam_role_arn}"]` throws the below error

> A managed resource "eks_managed_node_groups" "incidents-primary-ng" has not been declared in
> the root module

However, it works if I output it in the root module

When I checked the source code https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v19.15.3/node_groups.tf#L273 I see that

```
#value of var.eks_managed_node_groups below
incidents-primary-ng = {
  min_size     = 1
  max_size     = 2
  desired_size = 1
}
```

will be created by `for_each`

```
module "eks_managed_node_group" {
  source = "./modules/eks-managed-node-group"

  for_each = { for k, v in var.eks_managed_node_groups : k => v if var.create && !local.create_outposts_local_cluster }
  ...
}
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the current code? Any errors. Also you haven't provided what is the value of `var.eks_managed_node_groups`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have formatted my question and explained a bit better. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what causes your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your module is called `eks_managed_node_group`, but you are trying to refer to it as `eks_managed_node_groups`, which is incorrect name.